# GitHub action setup-r-dependencies fails stating there is no package called 'digest'

Tags: r, github, github-actions

I've been trying to set up some GitHub actions to automatically check my R package and run test coverage. I am currently using the action setup-r-dependencies@v2 to install the dependencies but it is failing to install the package 'digest'. Returning the following error:

```
 Error: Error: <callr_remote_error: Cannot install packages:
  * deps::.: there is no package called ‘digest’>
   in process 8254 
  -->
  <simpleError: Cannot install packages:
  * deps::.: there is no package called ‘digest’>
```

The dependencies in the package are as follows:

```
Imports:
    assertthat,
    crayon,
    forcats,
    rmarkdown,
    purrr,
    ggplot2,
    htmltools,
    lubridate,
    dplyr,
    tidyselect,
    rlang,
    INLA,
    arm,
    magrittr,
    glue,
    googleAuthR,
    googleCloudStorageR,
    stringr
```

Finally, the workflow itself that is failing looks like this (taken from the tidyverse packages):

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, dev]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, dev]

name: test-coverage

jobs:
  test-coverage:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Set up R 
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
          use-public-rspm: true

      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          extra-packages: any::covr
          needs: coverage

      - name: Test coverage
        run: covr::codecov(quiet = FALSE)
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

I have this same workflow working in another package and covr depends on digest which is getting installed in that package workflow. I'm left thinking that it must be to do with the package imports but I can't figure it out and would appreciate any help.

Not all of these packages are listed on CRAN.

Comment: are all of your imports available on CRAN

Comment: No, not all of them.

Comment: ok, are they available on github or some other repo?

Comment: you might have to add an r script under the install dependencies section of the GH action like so `run: |
          install.packages(c("remotes", "rcmdcheck", "covr"), repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
          remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
          remotes::install_github("repo/package")`

Comment: this will install packages from github and then be available for your test coverage. @ColinDaglish if this works I will submit as an answer

Comment: @Mike, thank you for your suggestion, your approach does install the required dependencies but it's insufferably slow, and impractical to use in our workflow. 

We are looking to understand why the digest package cannot be found using the `r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2` in this workflow.
- We know the 'digest' package exists, and it exists in R studio package manager as a binary version. 
- We also know that this exact workflow seems to run on our other package repository.

Comment: ok instead of my solution can you try to add digest to the  extra-packages section `any::digest` also try to change this actions/checkout@v3 to actions/checkout@v2

Comment: We've tried this.
`any::digest` didn't work. 
same with v2.

Comment: Can you check the log in the Install dependencies section and see if digest is not installing correctly? Perhaps there is a system dependency missing preventing compilation?

Comment: vaguely related: I was having new issues after having deployed a pkgdown site through GH for a long time without issue. After futzing with the .yml for a while to troubleshoot, I just overwrote it with up-to-date yml from **usethis**: `usethis::use_github_action("pkgdown")`